# How do I determine for vector $\mathbf{v}$ coordinates $\left \lfloor \mathbf{v} \right \rfloor_E$ and $\left \lfloor \mathbf{v} \right \rfloor_b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ the canonical basis $E=\left (\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2},\mathbf{e_3}  \right )$ and $B=\left (\mathbf{b_1},\mathbf{b_2},\mathbf{b_3}  \right )$ with
$\mathbf{b_1}=(1,2,4)^T$, $\mathbf{b_2}=(0,-1,1)^T$ and $\mathbf{b_3}=(2,3,8)^T$.

How do I determine for vector $\mathbf{v}=2\mathbf{e_1}+\mathbf{e_2}+2\mathbf{e_3}$ coordinates $\left \lfloor \mathbf{v} \right \rfloor_E$ and $\left \lfloor \mathbf{v} \right \rfloor_b$ ?

Okay. I know what values of canonical are $\mathbf{e_1}=(1,0,0)$, $\mathbf{e_2}=(0,1,0)$ and $\mathbf{e_3}=(0,0,1)$. But still I don't understand how do I get value of vector and it's coordinates.

If someone could help me I would be really thankful.